# Docker Sveltekit frontend requests to Laravel backend are returning 419

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, sveltekit

I've got a dockerized app with a frontend in `Sveltekit` and a backend API in `Laravel`.

I've got two `docker-compose` files, one for `development` and the other for `production`.

When running `development` my app works as expected. I can fetch data from the backend and also create and update data.

But when building and running `production` I can only fetch data from the backend. Meaning that only `GET` requests are going through, all other requests (`POST`, `PUT`, etc) are not.

I added some logs in my frontend apps and this is the response from a `POST`:

```
{ status: 419, data: undefined }
```

the URL used to perform requests is:

```
baseURL = "http://host.docker.internal:8000/api/";
```

I don't believe it's an issue related to the URL since as I mentioned before `GET` requests from the frontend work just fine.

This is my production `docker-compose` file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: dmc
    container_name: dmc-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www/
    depends_on:
      - db
      - nginx
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/
#      - ./docker/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
      - ./docker/php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini
      - ./images:/public/images
    networks:
      - dmc-net

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.23.2-alpine
    container_name: dmc-nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker-compose/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - dmc-net

  supervisor:
    build: .
    container_name: dmc-supervisor
    command: /var/www/artisan queue:work --sleep=4 --tries=3
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - app
      - nginx
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/
    networks:
      - dmc-net

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.31
    container_name: dmc-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    # using 3307 on the host machine to avoid collisions in case there's a local MySQL instance installed already.
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    # use the variables declared in .env file
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: abcd1234
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./docker-compose/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - dmc-net

  dmc-web:
    build:
      context: /Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-ui
      dockerfile: /Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-ui/Dockerfile
      target: prod
    container_name: dmc-web
    restart: always
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - ORIGIN=http://localhost:3000
    ports:
      - "1313:3000"
      - "5137:5137"
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      # it avoids mounting the workspace root
      # because it may cause OS specific node_modules folder
      # or build folder(.svelte-kit) to be mounted.
      # they conflict with the temporary results from docker space.
      # this is why many mono repos utilize ./src folder
      - /Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-ui/src:/app/src
      - /Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-ui/static:/app/app/static
      - /Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-ui/static:/app/static/
    depends_on:
      - app
      - nginx
      - db
    links:
      - app
    networks:
      - dmc-net

networks:
  dmc-net:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

Any idea what's going on?

Thanks.

Comment: when consuming the api resource, do you need `csrf_token`? Since 419 is mostly about missing csrf_token

Comment: I don't think I do @Mr.Kenneth. I mean, if I perform a `POST` request from a REST client it goes through with no need of `csrf_token`. The only headers I'm passing are `Content-Type` and `Accept`, that's all

Comment: `csrf_token` are just tokens. Can be declared as `{{csrf_token}}` in blade or `X-XSRF-TOKEN` in header. Maybe you are missing that. Also check if you are using `http-only` cookies too. If so, then you would probably need to set axios or ajax to use use them automatically. In axios, it is `withCredentials` to true. I am still referring to missing tokens here. But if it really is not because of csrf_tokens, then please ignore this comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem related to [Laravel](https://laravel.com/)'s [CSRF](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/csrf) (Cross-Site Request Forgery) protection, which can be disabled in the development environment (but not in production).
Laravel requires a CSRF token for all POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, and POST requests to protect against CSRF attacks. That token must be included in the request's headers or as a request parameter. A 419 status code typically indicates that the request failed CSRF verification.

First, temporarily disable CSRF protection on a test route in Laravel to confirm that the issue is CSRF-related. If the request succeeds, the problem is almost certainly with how CSRF tokens are handled.

Make sure your SvelteKit frontend is correctly configured to send the CSRF token with the requests. For Laravel, this token can be retrieved from a meta tag within your [blade template (csrf_token() function)](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/csrf#preventing-csrf-requests) or from a cookie ([XSRF-TOKEN](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/csrf#csrf-x-xsrf-token)). SvelteKit needs to include this token in the headers of the requests it sends to the Laravel backend.

```js
// Fetch the CSRF token from Laravel
const csrfToken = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;

// Include the CSRF token in your POST request headers
fetch('http://host.docker.internal:8000/api/your-endpoint', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    // Your request payload
  }),
});
```

If your Laravel application is setting cookies that are strictly `SameSite`, make sure your frontend and backend are served from the same domain or adjust the [`SameSite` attribute of your cookies](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types). In a production environment, differing domains or subdomains without proper `SameSite` configuration can cause issues.
If the token is stored in a cookie (`XSRF-TOKEN`), you might need to configure your HTTP client to send this token as a header (`X-XSRF-TOKEN`) with each request.

Also, make sure your [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) policy is correctly configured to allow requests from your SvelteKit frontend to your Laravel backend. Although this typically results in CORS errors rather than 419 errors, misconfiguration can lead to various request issues. See "[How do I use a different backend API server?](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/faq#how-do-i-use-x-with-sveltekit-how-do-i-use-a-different-backend-api-server)".

---

> Since in this case, Laravel is used only for API management and the UI is separate and knows nothing about the API, how do we get the XSRF token from a stateless API calls?
> When performing a login, is this token returned so it can be set in a cookie (or whatever other means) on the UI?

APIs are typically stateless and do not maintain session information between requests?
And... Laravel's CSRF protection do rely on sessions. So it may not be directly applicable or required for API routes.

Laravel can [exclude routes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris) within the `api` middleware group from CSRF protection, under the assumption that API endpoints will be accessed "statelessly", typically using tokens (like API tokens or JWTs) for authentication. CSRF tokens are primarily a defense mechanism against attacks that exploit authenticated sessions in web applications
That means that for purely API-driven interactions, CSRF protection might not be necessary if you are using token-based authentication methods.
You can see an illustration of that idea in the 2021 article "[How to Disable CSRF protection on specific Routes in Laravel](https://techverse.net/disable-csrf-protection-specific-routes-laravel/)" by Lovejeet.

> My only option was to disable CSRF protection on the specific API route. Without this, the external script would not have been able to post data to the laravel app.

If you still need to implement CSRF protection for certain stateful interactions or want to maintain a layer of CSRF protection for your API, you can design your API to provide a CSRF token endpoint. That endpoint can be called by the frontend to fetch a CSRF token when needed (e.g., before performing a POST request).

You can create a dedicated route in Laravel that generates and returns a CSRF token. That token can then be stored on the client-side (e.g., in local storage or as a cookie) and included in subsequent API requests that require CSRF protection.

```php
Route::get('/csrf-token', function () {
    return response()->json(['csrf_token' => csrf_token()]);
});
```

The frontend application can fetch this token and include it in the headers of requests that need CSRF protection, like you would with traditional form submissions.

```js
// Fetch the CSRF token from the API
fetch('http://your-api.com/csrf-token')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        const csrfToken = data.csrf_token;
        // Store the CSRF token for later use in requests
    });

// Include the CSRF token in an API request
fetch('http://your-api.com/protected-route', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken, // Use the stored token
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        // Your request payload
    }),
});
```

If you are using Laravel to handle authentication, you might choose to return a CSRF token as part of the login response. The frontend application can then store this token and use it for future requests that require CSRF protection.

Comment: since in this case Laravel is used only for API management and the UI is separate and knows nothing about the API, how do we get the XSRF token from a stateless API calls? When performing a login, is this token returned so it can be set in a cookie (or whatever other means) on the UI?